# Java last occurence of regex till end of string

Tags: java, regex, string

I need a regex that gets the text between the last occurrence of .java;[number] or java;NONE  and the end of the string.

Here's an example of the text I have as input:

```
user: ilian
branch: HEAD
changed files:
FlatFilePortfolioImportController.java;1.78
ConvertibleBondParser.java;1.52
OptionKnockedOutException.java;1.1.2.1
RebatePayoff.java;NONE

possible dead-lock. The suggested solution is to first create a TransactionContext and then lock AccountableDataFactory.IMPORT_LOCK and PositionManagerSQL
```

Basically I need to get the comment at the end of the commit, which is after the last changed file, which could end in something like 1.52, 1.1.2.1 or NONE.

Comment: The question would be much more clear if you explicitly say what should be the output in your example input.

Comment: @JiriKremser I think it goes from "possible dead-lock" until the end of the input. I was confused as well at first, had to change my answer as I though OP meant to extract the version number (!)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String comment = mydata.replaceAll("(?s).*java;[0-9,.]+|.*java;NONE", "");
System.out.println(comment);
```

Works for all the file endings and prints correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
String regex = "\\.java;\\d+\\.\\d+(.+)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**
Solution assuming input is in a single line (lines in original post only for clarity, see OP's comment below).

```
String input = "user: ilian branch: "
        + "HEAD changed files: "
        + "FlatFilePortfolioImportController.java;1.78 "
        + "ConvertibleBondParser.java;1.52 "
        + "possible dead-lock. The suggested solution is to first create a "
        + "TransactionContext and then lock AccountableDataFactory.IMPORT_LOCK "
        + "and PositionManagerSQL";
// checks last occurrence of java;x.xx, optional space(s), anything until end of input
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+java;[\\d\\.]+\\s+?(.+?)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
possible dead-lock. The suggested solution is to first create a TransactionContext and then lock AccountableDataFactory.IMPORT_LOCK and PositionManagerSQL
```

Comment: The output is in a single line, so \n doesn't work.
I need the left side to be the last occurrence of something like .java;(decimal), after that comes <the stuff I want>, and the right side should be (end of input), which should be \Z if I'm not mistaken.